# Get data in specific DIV with DOM

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I got a problem when i try to get data from a specific DIV, i got a blank return.

the link of the product: `www.phoneaxe.fr/info.php?id=15921`

and here my code to extract price

```
$nodeList_price = $dom->getElementsbytagname('div');
foreach ($nodeList_price as $node_price)
{
    if($node_price->getAttribute('class') == 'prix_info')
    {
        var_dump($node_price->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Thx in advance for help

Comment: it works, it says `Se connecter`

Comment: yes, i see but, when u r on the website u r able to see the price without logged in, why with curl i see "se connecter"

Comment: it seems javascript loads the price, you can't scrape it this way

Comment: when i use this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=5d824ac20a3fb9974ee6dcafc891db14'); for example i can extract the price, but how to generate a new each time ?

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to store the session cookie, perhaps?